# merge find command output with another command output and redirect to file

Tags: linux, bash, merge, find

I am looking to combine the output of the Linux find and head commands (to derive a list of filenames) with output of another Linux/bash command and save the result in a file such that each filename from the "find" occurs with the other command output on a separate line.

So for example, 
- if a dir *testdir* contains files a.txt, b.txt and c.txt, 
- and the output of the other command is some number say 10, the desired output I'm looking for is

```
10 a.txt
10 b.txt
10 c.txt
```

On searching here, I saw folks recommending paste for doing similar merging but I couldn't figure out how to do it in this scenario as paste seems to be expecting files . I tried

```
paste  $(find testdir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.text" | head -2) $(echo "10") >  output.txt
paste: 10: No such file or directory
```

Would appreciate any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong. Any other ways of achieving the same thing are also welcome.

Note that if I wanted to make everything appear on the same line, I could use xargs and that does the job.

```
$find testdir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.text" | head -2 |xargs echo "10" >  output.txt

$cat output.txt
10 a.txt b.txt
```

But my requirement is to merge the two command outputs as shown earlier.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `$(...)` is "Command Substitution" it replaces the command with a string of the output. `<(...)` is "Procession Substituion" and replaces the command with a file-like object. So you would want `<(...)` in your paste command. That said paste needs even numbers of lines from both sources and your command doesn't have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` can handle both the `-exec` and `-print` directives, you just need to merge the output:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*.txt -exec echo hello \; -print | paste - -
hello   ./b.txt
hello   ./a.txt
hello   ./all.txt
```

Assuming your "command" requires the filename (here's a very contrived example):

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*.txt -exec sh -c 'wc -l <"$1"' _ {} \; -print | paste - -
4   ./b.txt
4   ./a.txt
7   ./all.txt
```

Of course, that's executing the command for each file. To restrict myself to your question:

```
cmd_out=$(echo 10)
for file in *.txt; do
    echo "$cmd_out $file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$find testdir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.text" | head -2 |tr ' ' '\n'|sed -i 's/^/10/' >  output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The command as is gives the error "sed: no input files". There is some conflict or something is not escaped right.

Comment: Seems like its the -i flag that is not working correctly - if I save the output of the command uptil the sed into a file and then do a sed on the file, it works. So need to figure out how to make sed -i work properly.

Comment: On some platforms, you have to provide a backup suffix as an argument to -i (i.e. `sed -i.bak ...`)

Comment: Could not get it to work even with the backup suffix. sed is expecting the commandline to be files.

Comment: @mailforbiz as per above solutions you already got a perfect one, so why you trying this one again, also mentioning in my system i detect no such problem, it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `xargs` operate on one line at a time using `-L1`:

```
find testdir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.text" | xargs -L1 echo "10" >  output.txt
```

Comment: yes this works also and is faster than the paste it seems. Thanks!